# get all attributes for entity from core data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

how does my fetchedResultsController method look like, if I want to fetch all my attributes for an entity from core data? I only know and understand how to fetch data for a tableView and I think that is where all my confusion is coming from.
Here is my Core-Data setup:
[image]

I'm trying to fill an array with all the Attributes my Setting entity has and the show those values via NSLog output in my debug console.

Here is what I changed so far:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObject *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //NSManagedObject *newSetting = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newEntry setValue: @"StudiSoft" forKey:@"settingName"];


        if (_overrideSysTimeSwitch.on) {
            [newEntry setValue: @YES forKey:@"settingSysTimeOverride"];
            //editSetting.settingSysTimeOverride = @YES;
            NSLog(@"IF A");
        } else {
            //[newEntry setValue: @NO forKey:@"settingSysTimeOverride"];
            //editSetting.settingSysTimeOverride = @NO;
            NSLog(@"IF B");
        }


        if (_timeFormatSwitch.on) {
            //[newEntry setValue: @YES forKey:@"settingTimeFormat"];
            //editSetting.settingTimeFormat = @YES;
            NSLog(@"IF C");
        } else {
            //[newEntry setValue: @NO forKey:@"settingTimeFormat"];
            //editSetting.settingTimeFormat = @NO;
            NSLog(@"IF D");
        }
        [self.settingsArray addObject:@"StudiSoft"];


        NSError *error;
        [context save:&error];
```

I'm using this code-snipped that and I'm able to modify the core data content.
However, every time I run this code, it of course adds a new object.

I've been looking for a way to update existing Attributes in my Entity, or modify them, but I could NOT find them.
Anyhow this is a good step into the right direction.

I created a completely new project, with just one view, once I have it working on the main view I'm going to experiment with segues....

But for now, how would I update or change existing attributes?

Thanks guys!!

This is my editSave Method to store some data in core data:

```
- (IBAction)editSave:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if ([_editSaveButton.title isEqualToString:@"Edit"])
    {
        [self setTitle:@"Edit Settings"];
        //self.title = @"Edit Settings";

        _overrideSysTimeSwitch.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _timeFormatSwitch.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        _editSaveButton.title = @"Save";
    } else if ([_editSaveButton.title isEqualToString:@"Save"])
    {
        [self setTitle:@"Settings"];
        //self.title = @"Settings";

        _overrideSysTimeSwitch.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        _timeFormatSwitch.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        _editSaveButton.title = @"Edit";

        // #############################################################
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        //NSManagedObject *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        //[newEntry setValue: @"StudiSoft" forKey:@"settingName"];


        /*NSString *firstName = [anEmployee firstName];
        Employee *manager = anEmployee.manager;
        Setting *newSetting = [NSString @"Test"];

        [newSetting setValue:@"Stig" forKey:@"settingName"];
        [aDepartment setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:100000] forKeyPath:@"manager.salary"];*/

        //editSetting.settingName = @"Test";



        if (_overrideSysTimeSwitch.on) {
            //[newEntry setValue: @YES forKey:@"settingSysTimeOverride"];

            editSetting.settingSysTimeOverride = @YES;
            NSLog(@"IF A");
        } else {
            //[newEntry setValue: @NO forKey:@"settingSysTimeOverride"];

            editSetting.settingSysTimeOverride = @NO;
            NSLog(@"IF B");
        }


        if (_timeFormatSwitch.on) {
            //[newEntry setValue: @YES forKey:@"settingTimeFormat"];

            editSetting.settingTimeFormat = @YES;
            NSLog(@"IF C");
        } else {
            //[newEntry setValue: @NO forKey:@"settingTimeFormat"];

            editSetting.settingTimeFormat = @NO;
            NSLog(@"IF D");
        }
        //[self.settingsArray addObject:@"StudiSoft"];


        NSError *error = nil;
        //if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
            //NSLog(@"SAVE & DISMISS conetx has changed");
            if (![context save:&error]) {                 // save failed
                NSLog(@"Save failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else {                                                        // save succeeded
                NSLog(@"Save Succeeded");
            }
        //}

        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        // #############################################################
    }
}
```

Debug Output:

```
2014-06-10 19:09:29.881 SettingsCoreData[508:60b] Entry #5: <Setting: 0x8f983e0> (entity: Setting; id: 0x8f97030 <x-coredata://FA78AB86-3225-4B1E-97DD-3F31F5323A18/Setting/p6> ; data: {
    settingName = StudiSoft;
    settingSysTimeOverride = 0;
    settingTimeFormat = 0;
})
2014-06-10 19:09:29.883 SettingsCoreData[508:60b] Entry #6: <Setting: 0x8f98430> (entity: Setting; id: 0x8f97040 <x-coredata://FA78AB86-3225-4B1E-97DD-3F31F5323A18/Setting/p7> ; data: {
    settingName = StudiSoft;
    settingSysTimeOverride = 1;
    settingTimeFormat = 1;
})
```

Now I should be able to use something like this in my viewDidLoad, right?

```
if (editSetting.settingSysTimeOverride.boolValue == 0) {
        _overrideSysTimeSwitch.on = NO;
    } else {
        _overrideSysTimeSwitch.on = YES;
    }
```

But it doesn't work as I thought it will :-(

Answer (score 1):

Next you need to call `-performFetch:` on the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Make sure you check the response and handle the error if the response is `NO`.

From there your `NSFetchedResultsController` is populated and ready to be used.  You can then grab individual elements via `-objectAtIndex:` or you can grab them all with `-fetchedObjects`.

I would suggest just reviewing the documentation on the methods that are available as it has pretty strong and clear documentation.

### Update

If you are not receiving any data then break it down.  Take the `NSFetchRequest` that you created and call `-executeFetchRequest:error:` against your `NSManagedObjectContext` and see if you get any data back.

- If you do then there is something wrong with your handling of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.
- If you don't then there is something wrong with your `NSFetchRequest` or you don't have any data in your store.

### Update

Sounds like you need to read a book on how Core Data works.

A `NSFetchRequest` is a query against Core Data so that objects can be returned from the store.  You can pass a `NSFetchRequest` to a `NSFetchedResultsController` so that the `NSFetchedResultsController` can monitor the store for changes and let your view controller know when those changes occur.

A `NSFetchRequest` can also be executed directly against the `NSManagedObjectContext` and you can retrieve the results directly.  You do that by calling `-executeFetchRequest:error:` against your `NSManagedObjectContext` and getting a `NSArray` back.  You can then check that `NSArray` to see if you get any results.

If you do not understand that paragraph then you need to take a step back and read the tutorials on Core Data and/or read a book on Core Data.  I can recommend an excellent book on the subject ;-)

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for your reply, I do have the -performFetch: in my viewDidLoad, see updated question above, but still it for some reason doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just can't figure out what's wrong.
my project is here:
http://d01.megashares.com/dl/a0TViuE/CoreDataFix.zip
If someone could look at it please... I've been stuck on this problem for over a week now and getting so frustrated to completely throw this iOS Dev over board :-(

Comment: Did you follow the steps I suggested?  I am not going to solve it for you but I am happy to walk you through the steps to debug your problem.

Comment: Hi
isn't that what I did in my viewDidLoad?
if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        abort();
    }

Other than that, how would I call executeFetchedRequest:error against my NSManagedObject??

I'm confused?!

Comment: Anyhow,
this is my debugger output when it crashes, it stops at that abort(); as expected with an exception
I also added settingName attribute of type String to core data, to see if the bool values confuse things.

The debug Output is in my edited original post, as it's too long for comments...
Thanks Marcus!!!!!!

Comment: Your debug output shows you are getting zero rows back.  There is something wrong with your predicate or you have no data in your store.

Comment: Hey Marcus,
please don't give up on me yet :-) And thanks for trying!
I modified the fetchedResultsController method and I'm actually calling the -executeFetchRequest:error:, but there it doesn't return an error.
I get my NSLog statement "No error", but when it jumps back to the viewDidLoad, that's when the error causes an exception and my abort() is triggered.

I updated the original post above to show the new fetchedResultsController method, also I tried to set my entities' attributes to some default values, to see if that makes a difference, as I haven't changed any values yet.

Comment: I did change the default values of some of my attributes in core data, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Again, you are getting zero rows back.  You either have something wrong with your predicate or no data in your store for your Setting entity.  Ignore the NSFetchedResultsController and solve the problem of not getting any data back.  Since you don't have a `NSPredicate` attached to your `NSFetchRequest` you probably need to find out why you don't have any data in your store.

Comment: I don't have any data in my core data yet, as I never had write access to it yet, all that is in there are default values.
Default values that I changed, as stated before, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: You don't have anything in your Settings entity.  I don't know what you think you have in there, but there is nothing.  You can confirm that by going to disk, using the SQLite CLI and looking at the underlying table.  It will be empty.

Comment: Hi,
ok I removed the abort(); statement, and of course now it works. I'm just not dealing with the empty core data. I changed the default values of my attributes and added another attribute of type string and gave that one a default value too.
But I guess it doesn't matter, the core data db is still empty, right?
how do other applications deal with this situation?
At some point there is NO information in there, until it initially gets put in there..

Comment: Other applications deal with it in many ways; user input; preloading the database; loading from a server; loading from a file; the list goes on. The answer is extremely broad and 100% dependent on the goals of your application.

Comment: Hi,
I changed some things around and I read again through the docs at apple.com. Anyhow I modified my code based on what I read so far.
See my edit above please

Comment: I don't see any edits to your post.  There is nothing to test in your code until you get data into the store.  I am not sure what the communications gap is but put some data into the store then you can start testing code.

Comment: sorry, I added the comment then updated the code.
I should be able to use accessors right?
        Setting *newSetting = [NSString @"Test"];
        
        [newSetting setValue:@"Stig" forKey:@"settingName"];
is what I'm trying now...
"Setting" is in my header-file as
@property (nonatomic, strong)Setting *editSetting;

does that seem right so far?

Comment: See edits for my editSave method, which should throw some data in core data

Comment: I hit the edit/save button multiple times and toggled the switches, see debug output in main post

Comment: Hey Marcus, bought your book. Thanks for the advice, hope it is easier to understand than apples documentation!
Thanks again for your help through-out this.